# Cannot bind port less than 1024 in native C socket for Android app

Tags: android, c, sockets, java-native-interface

I am trying to port a TCP server implemented in C to Android. The C code is used as a native lib in my Android app.

So far, the code works fine if the server listening port is >= 1024, but if the port is below 1024 then the app won't run properly.

**(In case of you are wondering why the app needs to bind a privileged port < 1024: This app is not intended to run on generic Android phones/tablets, instead it is to be running on a dedicated Android embedded device for which I will build a custom ROM from AOSP source, and host some standard services like HTTP, FTP, etc)**

On Linux, binding a standard port requires `su`, but on Android what should I do to make the binding successful? Does the app need root access, and/or a customized SELinux policy? Are there any online documents related to this topic?

Below is what was shown in the log console when trying to bind port 1023. It seems the app keep restarting:

```
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (11493) for package com.example.tcp_server ----------------------------

---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (11493) for package com.example.tcp_server ----------------------------

---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (11524) for package com.example.tcp_server ----------------------------

---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (11524) for package com.example.tcp_server ----------------------------
```

Comment: Why does your app need a port less than 1024?

Comment: Android runs on top of Linux, and on Linux ports below 1024 are reserved for admin/system use, so don't expect this to work on Android without rooting the device.

Comment: @selbie, the app is not for generic Android phones/tablets. It is part of a dedicated Android embedded device whose ROM is built from source. On the device there will be some standard services running like HTTP, FTP.

Comment: @user2616158 Then your process must have `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` capability (and probably drop it after binding).

Comment: No matter if your device is a standard Android phone/tablet or a custom one. Android apps are always executed as a user inside the sandbox, thus an app (AFAIK even system apps) never has root privileges and thus can never make use of ports below 1024. If you want to make use these ports, do it outside of an app (regular Linux binary) and start it with root permissions.

Comment: @Robert, thanks for the info. I just entered Android from Linux development. Can you point me to some docs on these topics like how a Linux binary communicate with an Android app?

Comment: Sorry, but that topic is only relevant if you develop an own Android ROM (which I never did). Thus I don't have an answer for you.